# Index won't up of List

Tags: c#, list, datagridview, indexing

I'm still learning in programming

I'm trying to get customer data in list. So I can get the value from the index, but it only can get the first customer. the index won't increment, I'm still confusing, I have already move the variable for increment the index won't work, maybe my logic isn't right. here's the code, tell me where is not right..?? thank you for you help and explanation

```
public void getJamVSpot()
{
    var listJamAwal = new List<String>();
    var listJamAkhir = new List<String>();
    var listNota = new List<int>();

    DateTime tglSewa = dtp_tglSewa.Value.Date;
    int r = 0;
    String ja = String.Empty;
    String jb = String.Empty;
    int n = 0;
    int indexUp = 0;

    if (dtp_tglSewa.Value.Date == jl.getTglJadwalVspot(tglSewa, lap) && rdb_Lapangan_VSpot.Checked == true || rdb_rumputSintetis.Checked == true)
    {

        IEnumerator<String> jAwal = jl.getJamAwalbyDate(tglSewa, lap);
        while (jAwal.MoveNext())
        {
            listJamAwal.Add(jAwal.Current);

        }
        IEnumerator<String> jAkhir = jl.getJamAkhirbyDate(tglSewa, lap);
        while (jAkhir.MoveNext())
        {
            listJamAkhir.Add(jAkhir.Current);

        }
        IEnumerator<int> nota = jl.getNota(tglSewa, lap);
        while (nota.MoveNext())
        {
            listNota.Add(nota.Current);

        }

        ja = listJamAwal[indexUp];
        jb = listJamAkhir[indexUp];
        n = listNota[indexUp];

        int count = jl.countNota(n);
        String penyewa = jl.getNamaPenyewa(n);
        String no_kontak = jl.getNomorKontak(n);
        String status = jl.getStatusSewa(n);

        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_Jadwal_Sewa.Rows)
                if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(ja))
                {
                    r = row.Index;

                    row.Cells[2].Value = penyewa;
                    row.Cells[3].Value = no_kontak;
                    row.Cells[4].Value = status;

                    if (ja != jb)
                    {
                        ja = jl.getJamAkhirbyJamAwal(ja);
                        row.Cells[2].Value = penyewa;
                        row.Cells[3].Value = no_kontak;
                        row.Cells[4].Value = status;
                        //dgv_Jadwal_Sewa.Rows[r].Selected = true;

                    }
                    break;
                }
        }

    } indexUp++;
}
```

[image]

Comment: you can see the result on here http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/2295/i84.png

Comment: Yep put `indexUp++` inside your `for` loop.  Though i'd recommend looking at the `DataTable` class and binding your `DataGridView` to a table.  Takes alot of the work out of this.

Comment: I've tried insert into loop, still won't work, I have try to put it on above of break;

Comment: Even if you move the `indexUp` inside the loop so it gets incremented, you're still not making use of the new values. You only make use of `indexUp` outside the loop. You use the value to get `count` which in turn is used to iterate through the loop again...

Comment: If you single step your code and inspect the values while doing so, you will probably figure out what is wrong.  I recommend that you change the way you use the IEnumerable to the more convenient foreach-methods.

Comment: hmm,, I'm still learning,, and try to get understand,, because the limit of my english. thank you,,, I'll try what you are tried told me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you increment the `indexUp` variable you aren't using it anymore.

In your code you are just recovering the first item (0), doing some stuff with this value (in the loops) and exits.

For example, you can wrap your stuff with this loop:

```
    for (int indexUp = 0; indexUp < listJamAwal.Count; indexUp++)
    {
        ja = listJamAwal[indexUp];
        jb = listJamAkhir[indexUp];
        n = listNota[indexUp];

        int count = jl.countNota(n);

        String penyewa = jl.getNamaPenyewa(n);
        String no_kontak = jl.getNomorKontak(n);
        String status = jl.getStatusSewa(n);

        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_Jadwal_Sewa.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(ja))
                {
                    r = row.Index;

                    row.Cells[2].Value = penyewa;
                    row.Cells[3].Value = no_kontak;
                    row.Cells[4].Value = status;

                    if (ja != jb)
                    {
                        ja = jl.getJamAkhirbyJamAwal(ja);
                        row.Cells[2].Value = penyewa;
                        row.Cells[3].Value = no_kontak;
                        row.Cells[4].Value = status;
                        //dgv_Jadwal_Sewa.Rows[r].Selected = true;
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you sir... I'm really thank you... thank's for the help, and tell me where is the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with how you access the items:

- You assign the variables outside the loop. That will get the values that the index points to at that moment, and changing the index variable later doesn't change what's assigned to the variables. You have to assign the variables inside the loop, except the `count` variable of course which you need before the loop starts.
- You are incrementing the `indexUp` variable after the loop, when you have no use for it any more. You have to put that inside the loop so that it can be used in the next iteration to read new values into the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any point of using first loop with "i" and then second with foreach. Its totally wrong - you are doing the same thing "count" times! 
You also need to change penyewa, no_kontak, status because you are using same values inside loop

And in addition, I have never seen so confusing and unclear variable naming, you should change it if you want some else to use it :D